# How can one say “good morning” in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, salutations

I've usually been told just to say “*bonjour*” in French when in English one would want to emphasize that it is early and you are greeting them in the morning, and would therefore say “good morning”.  Given the legitimacy of phrases like “*bonne après-midi*” which *does* emphasize the time of day, is there a way to convey the meaning of something like “good morning” in French, or must one just use the generic “good day”?

Comment: Je dirais que c'est *Bonjour*.

Comment: I know both can now be accepted, as (wrong) use makes law, but I'd prefer 'Bon après midi'.

Comment: Un peu trop de personnes répètent qu'il est mieux de dire « bon après-midi » que « bonne après-midi ». C'est faux dans le sens où le mot *après-midi* fait partie des mots auxquels on n'a pas attribué un genre : [il est ainsi féminin *ou* masculin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/apr%C3%A8s-midi). Donc, les deux — *bon* et *bonne* — sont corrects.

Comment: in québec, simply *Bon matin*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On peut dire "bonne matinée" en français, tout comme on dit "bon après-midi". Cela dit, on n'utilise ces formes que lorsqu'on quitte un lieu, et jamais lorsqu'on y arrive.

"Bonne matinée" est donc plus l'équivalent de "Have a good morning" que de "Good morning". Il n'y a pas d'équivalent de "Good morning" lorsqu'on rencontre une personne, on se contente de dire "Bonjour".

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu *Bonne matinée* (en Belgique du moins) mais pourquoi pas.

Comment: En France, "bonne matinée" s'utilise comme "bon après-midi" et "bonne soirée", au moment de quitter une personne.

Comment: Moi non plus. J'ai l'impression qu'on utilise plus Bonjour le matin et puis bon après-midi et bonne soirée le soir

Comment: J'habite Paris, en 15 ans jamais entendu "bonne matinée".

Comment: -1, jamais entendu "bonne matinée".

Comment: Au Québec, il est très courant de dire "Bon matin".

Comment: Jamais entendu "bonne matinée" non plus. Je dis plutôt "bonne journée" en partant, sauf le soir "bonne soirée"... un peu moins souvent "bon après-midi" ! Mais si je connais bien la personne, je dis très souvent "salut" ou "coucou" ("salut" pour partir aussi).

Comment: Je dirais *bonne matinée* en quittant une personne uniquement si je l'ai recontrée très tôt (en arrivant au travail par exemple) et uniquement si on sait tous les deux qu'on va se revoir aux alentours de midi, pour manger par exemple. S'il n'y a pas une excellente raison de penser qu'on se reverra à midi je dirais *bonne journée*.

Answer (score 27):

It's more subtle than that.

- *Bonjour* and *bonsoir* are terms that are used as salutations when you arrive in a place, or meet someone. Those are the only two alternatives that I can think of, and have no variant for morning or middle of the night.
- *Bonne matinée*, *bonne journée*, *bon après-midi* (or *bonne après-midi*), *bonne soirée*, *bonne nuit* are salutations that you use upon departing. There is a much larger gamut, and you can create new ones without problem (*bonne fin d'après-midi* to someone with whom you spent the first two hours of the afternoon, say).

Comment: Similar to "Good Day" or "Good Day, Sir." -- said emphatically to someone to indicate that the conversation is over, even though the expressed feeling is different.
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I+said+good+day!

Answer (score 7):

You can say:

- *Bonjour* usually when you meet someone for the first time in the day. And also *Bonne journée* which is rather used when you leave someone during the day and often used in sentence like “Je vous souhaite une bonne journée”, or “Passe une bonne journée”
- *Bonne après-midi*, *Bonne soirée* is also used when leaving people. There is no term to introduce oneself in the afternoon, but you can use *Bonsoir* in the evening instead of *Bonjour*.

Comment: Un après-midi est plus correct.

Comment: @wok Ok l'académie note que le masculin est mieux. La version féminine existe néanmoins, quoique plus utilisé dans le jargon populaire que formel.

Answer (score 7):

There is no good translation for “Good morning”.
People just say “Bonjour” or “Salut”.

“Bonne matinée” means “Have a good morning (in the future)”. People say that instead of saying “good bye”.

Likewise:

> *Bonne aprèm* ⟶ Have a good afternoon
>
> *Bonne soirée* ⟶ Have a good evening
>
> *Bonne nuit* ⟶ Have a good night
>
> *Bonne journée* ⟶ Have a good day

If you really want to emphasize on the morning, the following sentences are quite common:

> *La journée commence bien ?*
>
> *Ça va, ce matin ?*
>
> *Tout va bien, ce matin ?*
>
> *Tu passes une bonne matinée ?*

Answer (score 5):

*Bon après-midi* would only be used instead of *au revoir*.

For **greetings**, you can use *Bonjour*. And after 4 p.m., it is more polite to use *Bonsoir*.

Comment: 4 p.m seems very early to me to say bonsoir. I never use it before 6 or 7 p.m

Comment: That's why I don't like to say 'Bonsoir', I never know when I can start to use it... It's always the morning somewhere in the world :-)

Comment: Dans certains endroits du Berry *bonsoir* signifie *au revoir* et peut être utilisé dès le matin en partant !

Comment: I used to start using *Bonsoir* around 10-11 p.m., but thanks to Benoit, I'll use it a lot more now :)

Answer (score 5):

How to greet people is probably very region-dependant.

I would use *Bonjour* at any time of day when I greet someone; sometimes *Bonne journée* in the morning when there's still a full day ahead (and if I actually mean the person to have a good day). *Bon matin* exists too, but it may be unusual depending on where.

*Bonjour* est en général utilisé durant toute la journée et remplacé par *bonsoir* en soirée.

Au matin, j'utilise plutôt *bonne journée* (Si je le pense vraiment); mais <strike>*bon matin* ou</strike> *bonne matinée* pourrai<strike>en</strike>t aussi faire l'affaire.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "bon matin".

Comment: Faut pas se lever à midi :-) (Sérieusement, c'est vrai que ce n'est pas très courant mais, même si [il paraît que c'est faux](http://french.about.com/od/mistakes/a/bonmatin.htm), je suis sûr que ça existe.)

Comment: j'ai bien peur que ce soit faux ;-)

Comment: j'ai bien peur que tu aies raison ;-)

Comment: "Bon matin" est effectivement utilisé dans certaines régions... mais cela ne signifie en rien qu'il s'agit d'une locution correcte.

Comment: J'ai déjà entendu ([au Québec](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/2077/1514)), et ma préférence va a *bon matin*, quitte à tenir à dire 'Good morning'.  @Kareen : je suis plutôt d'avis que ça devient correct si c'est utilisé.

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas Dans tous les bureaux de traduction où j'ai travaillé, *bon matin* faisait grincer des dents. *Si j'aurais* est également beaucoup utilisé, mais je ne dirais pas que c'est correct pour autant.

Comment: "Bon matin" est utilisé chaque jour au Québec par des milliers de personnes.

Answer (score 4):

En français québécois, il est correct de saluer quelqu’un en disant « bon matin ! ». Dans le reste de la francophonie, cette tournure est incorrecte : on se contentera d’un « bonjour ».

Comment: Elle fait par contre grincer bien des dents, surtout chez les professionnels de la langue, du moins chez les traducteurs et réviseurs avec lesquels j'ai travaillé.

Comment: Je suis français et elle me rebute aussi. Mais ça peut être intéressant de savoir cela lorsqu’on traduit à destination du Canada.

Answer (score 2):

En Suisse, on dit "Bon Dimanche" en se quittant à partir de Vendredi midi et jusqu'à Dimanche midi.

Quand j'étais petit, on le disait aussi la veille des jours fériés. Mais il a tendance à s’effacer devant le « Bonne fête » par assimilation au Frouse [=Français de France].